# Grouping the values of all columns by index of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I want to basically build a distribution of total no. of videos a user has watched. Watch is signified by 1 else 0. Users are index of the data frame.

Assume the data is like this:

```
A   B   C
User1   1   1   0
User2   0   1   0
User3   1   0   1
```

I want for each use a count of all the 1 in that row.

I am doing something like this but it doesn't seem to work. I dont want to use some applymap function as that seem to be slow.

```
d.groupby(d.index).sum(axis=1)
```

Gives error that axis not recognized

Comment: Does `df.sum(axis=1)` work?

Comment: Do you have duplicate entries in the index?

Comment: There is no duplicate index. Why is .sum(axis=1) not working?

Comment: np.sum(axis=1) works for numpy array

Answer (score 0):

If you have duplicates in index, you can use `groupby` with double `sum`:

```
print (df)
       A  B  C
User1  1  1  0
User1  1  1  1
User2  0  1  0
User3  1  0  1

print (df.groupby(df.index).sum().sum(1))
User1    5
User2    1
User3    2
dtype: int64
```

If there are no duplicates, use only `sum`- [Psidom comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38402574/grouping-the-values-of-all-columns-by-index-of-a-pandas-dataframe/38402963#comment64213355_38402574):

```
df.sum(axis=1)
```

EDIT:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df.sum(axis=1).plot.hist()
plt.show()
```

[image: graph]

Comment: Yeah df.sum(1) works. What do you say about getting a histogram of the sum() by the count of users? . Plotting the second column as x axis and the count of index as historgram

Comment: Nope it should be three graphs. One for each 1, 2 and 5. And count for these would be same since each have one user each.

Comment: So run this. df1= df.sum(axis=1); 
then run
df1.plot.bar()

The output you get I need the flipped. So basically x axis would be the first column of the df1 series and y axis would be the user count. 

I am trying groupy to get that but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: What about `df.sum(axis=1).plot.barh()` ?

Comment: No this is not what I want. I want the distribution of the user count by the total views. So basically if u look at the table above, I want to plot how many users have watched 1 video, how many have watched 2 and so on. In the above it would be three columns where for 1 , 2 , 5 we would would have values as 1, 1,1 since each have one user. I am using groupby like this: 

df1=d.sum(axis=1);
df1.groupby(df1).count(df1.index)

but it throws error in count

Comment: Maybe this works - `df.sum(axis=1).to_frame().groupby(level=0).plot.hist()`

Comment: Sorry, I have to go away. Good luck! And maybe you can upvote. Thanks.

Comment: You know I think this actually makes sense, but it is coming on separate graphs. It should all be in one plot.

Answer (score -1):

Use the **transpose** method of the DataFrame.

```
In [38]: d = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,0,1],'B':[1,1,0],'C':[0,0,1]},index=['User1','User2','User3'])

In [39]: d
Out[39]:
       A  B  C
User1  1  1  0
User2  0  1  0
User3  1  0  1

In [40]: d.transpose()
Out[40]:
   User1  User2  User3
A      1      0      1
B      1      1      0
C      0      0      1

In [41]: d.transpose().sum()
Out[41]:
User1    2
User2    1
User3    2
dtype: int64
```

Or, as Psidom suggested, sum the columns of your DataFrame.

```
In [55]: d.sum(axis=1)
Out[55]:
User1    2
User2    1
User3    2
dtype: int64
```

Comment: indeed, df.sum(axis=1) is the better solution